# JQUERY .slider() doesn't work - don't show anything

Tags: jquery, slider

I write this code and jquery don't show anything. I can't find where is a problem.
Need two slider with one handle and sets values min, max, start value. It doesn't work. Jquery don't show anything

```
 $(function() {                    
                $('#szerokosc_schematu').slider({
                    animate: fast,
                    orientation: vertical,
                    step: <?echo $step_szerokosc;?>,
                    create: function(event, ui){},
                    start: function(event, ui){},
                    slide: function(event, ui){},                        
                    change: function(event, ui) {
                        $('$szerokosc_value').attr('value', $(this).slider('value')),
                        $('#dlugosc_schematu').slider({value: $(this).slider('value')});
                    },      
                    stop: function(event, ui){},
                    value: <?echo $szerokosci['0'];?>,
                    min: <?echo $szerokosci['0'];?>,
                    max: <?echo $najw_szerokosc;?>
                    //values: [<? echo $szerokosci['0']; ?>,<?echo $najw_szerokosc;?>]

                });

                $( "#szerokosc_schematu").slider( "enable" );

                //var min_dlug = $("#szerokosc_schematu").slider("option","min");

                $('#dlugosc_schematu').slider({
                    animate: fast,
                    orientation: horizontal,
                    step: <?echo $step_dlugosci;?>,
                    create: function(event, ui){},
                    start: function(event, ui){},
                    slide: function(event, ui){},
                    change: function(event, ui) {
                        $('$dlugosc_value').attr('value', $(this).slider('value'));
                    },
                    stop: function(event, ui){},
                    value: <?echo $pierwsza_dlugosc;?>,
                    min: $("#szerokosc_schematu").slider("option","min"),
                    max: <?echo $pierwsza_dlugosc;?>
                    //values: [<?echo $pierwsza_dlugosc;?>,<?echo $najw_dlugosc;?>]

                });
                $( "#dlugosc_schematu").slider( "enable" );
  });
```

HTML BLOCK

```
        <div id="szerokosc_schematu"></div> 
        <div id="dlugosc_schematu"></div> 


        <input id="szerokosc_value" name="szerokosc_value"></input>
        <input id="dlugosc_value" name="szerokosc_value"></input>
```

In "jsfiddle.net" I don't see anything too. Somewhere is error but where?

### edit

I correct html block:

```
        <div id="dlugosc_schematu" class="ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
            <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" style="left: 0%;"></a>
        </div>
```

I see slider but it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you include corresponding js files for that?

Comment: I use Codeigniter framework:

<?php echo theme_js('jquery-1.6.2.min.js', true) ;?>
<?php echo theme_js('jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js', true) ;?>